# How I can display any format file in web browser My code is working for .png and .pdf files but not working for word file

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have one ActionUrl in application in that it contains address of files of all formats.

Now on click of any file it should be open in browser(Not to download)

I tried bellow code for it but its only working for pdf format.

```
public FileContentResult ViewFile(string filename)
{

string OnlyFileName = Path.GetFileName(filename);
string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

var mimeType = "application/pdf";

if (ext.ToLower() == ".png")
{
mimeType = "image/png";
}
else if (ext.ToLower() == ".docx")
{
mimeType = "application/ms-word";
}
//

var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

return new FileContentResult(fileContents, mimeType);
}
```

Comment: It is up to *browsers* how they react to different file types. If they don't support displaying a particular type of file, most will automatically assume a download.

Comment: Currently there's no browser have necessary code to render Word document format (only image & PDF recognized), but you can use MS Office Online Document Preview wrapped in iframe: `<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=@Url.Action("docx-file-URL")'></iframe>`.